# Get values of cells in dataframe column quickly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns has the format:

```
Items
3
3
3
5
5
11
11
11
11
16
16
...
```

I want to quickly get a single instance of every number (so for the example above I would need 3, 5, 11, and 16). Currently I have this:

```py
Item_set = set()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    Item_set.add(row['Items'])
```

But the dataframe is ~385,000 rows long so this process takes 15 minutes, is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: `df['Items'].unique()` gives you a list. Or if you want set: `set(df['Items'])` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to be working on something similar while I came across this question. Why not convert your Series to a numpy array and use np.unique()?
That's the fastest as per my knowledge.
Attached some code below.

```
%timeit y_data.unique()
105 µs ± 8.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.unique(list(y_data))
220 µs ± 32.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.unique(y_data.to_numpy())
23.3 µs ± 3.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

len(y_data)
Out[104]: 1281

type(y_data)
Out[109]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your Pandas Series `s`, `s.unique()` should do the job:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([3,3,3, 5, 5])
>>> s.unique()
array([3, 5])
```

If you need a set:

```
Item_set = set(s.unique())
```

Comment: `set(s.unique())` ?? set will give you unique elements only. Why to use set over unique elements?

Comment: To simply convert the object type from Array to Set